# SQL* Loader : Unable to load data with date column

Tags: sql, oracle11g, sql-loader

I'm trying to load data from csv file into db with SQL Loader. Table has a column "EXPIRY_DATE" as "DATE" type. Defined that field in control file as :

```
EXPIRY_DATE  "YYYY-MONTH-DD HH24:MI:SS"
```

And the CSV file contains the field in the below format.

```
2016-JUL-01 00:00:00
```

But when tyring to load the data SQLLoader is complaining with the error message :  **Invalid bind variable :MI in SQL string for column EXPIRY_DATE**

Tried changing the minutes to "MM", that dint' help either. 
What I'm i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
EXPIRY_DATE DATE 'YYYY-Mon-DD HH24:MI:SS'
```

You need to use `Mon` for the three letter abbreviation of a month rather than `MONTH`.  Also, I believe that you need to specify the `DATE` type when giving the format string.